# How to add custom attribute that take Type as an argument

Tags: .net, mono.cecil

I want to use Mono.Cecil to add a custom attribute to a method. The constructor of the custom attributes has a `System.Type`. I'm trying to figure out how to create such a custom attribute with Mono.Cecil and what is the argument for the System.Type parameter.

My attribute is defined as follows:

```
public class SampleAttribute : Attribute {
    public SampleAttribute (Type type) {}
}
```

So far I've tried:

```
var module = ...;
var method = ...;
var sampleAttributeCtor = ...;

var attribute = new CustomAttribute (sampleAttributeCtor);

attribute.ConstructorArguments.Add (
    new ConstructorArgument (module.TypeSystem.String, module.GetType ("TestType").FullName));
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Any idea?

I have updated the code as follows

```
var module=targetExe.MainModule;
            var anothermodule=sampleDll.MainModule;
            var custatt = new CustomAttribute(ctorReference);


            var corlib =module .AssemblyResolver.Resolve((AssemblyNameReference)module.TypeSystem.Corlib);
            var systemTypeRef = module.Import(corlib.MainModule .GetType("System.Type"));
            custatt.ConstructorArguments.Add(new CustomAttributeArgument(systemTypeRef, module.Import(anothermodule.GetType("SampleDll.Annotation"))));
            methodDef.CustomAttributes.Add(custatt);
```

any suggestions?

Comment: I don't mind answering Mono.Cecil questions, but you should make them easier to read and to help you. The code presented is messy, not colorized, and could be reduced to only a couple of lines I you think about what the question is. I'm going to edit this question to give you an example.

Answer (score 2):

Even though types in custom attributes are encoded using their full name as a string, Cecil abstracts that away for you.

The representation for a Type in Mono.Cecil is a `TypeReference` (or a `TypeDefinition` if the type comes from the same module).

You simply need to pass that as an argument. First you need to get a reference to the type `System.Type` to use as a type of the custom attribute argument.

```
var corlib = module.AssemblyResolver.Resolve ((AssemblyNameReference) module.TypeSystem.Corlib);
var systemTypeRef = module.Import (corlib.GetType ("System.Type"));
```

And then depending on where the type you want to use as an argument you can write:

```
attribute.ConstructorArguments.Add (
    new ConstructorArgument (
        systemTypeRef,
        module.GetType ("TestType")));
```

or if the type you're interested in is in another module, you need to import a reference:

```
attribute.ConstructorArguments.Add (
    new ConstructorArgument (
        systemTypeRef,
        module.Import (anotherModule.GetType ("TestType"))));
```

Comment: Hi,I have tried your solution and getting the error   "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

Comment: var custatt = new CustomAttribute(ctorReference);
         

           var corlib = inputmodule.AssemblyResolver.Resolve (inputmodule.TypeSystem.Corlib.Name);
           var systemTypeRef = inputmodule.Import(corlib.GetType());

             custatt.ConstructorArguments.Add(new CustomAttributeArgument(systemTypeRef, inputmodule.Import (anothermodule .GetType ("SampleDll.Annotation"))));
              methodDef.CustomAttributes.Add(custatt);

Comment: @MuruganAlagesan no you didn't. The value you initialize systemTypeRef with is not what I wrote.

Comment: Ok sir,I tried the following code as  you told still getting the same error

Comment: var module=targetExe.MainModule;
                var anothermodule=sampleDll.MainModule;
                var custatt = new CustomAttribute(ctorReference);
   

                var corlib =module .AssemblyResolver.Resolve((AssemblyNameReference)module.TypeSystem.Corlib);
                var systemTypeRef = module.Import(corlib.MainModule .GetType("System.Type"));
                custatt.ConstructorArguments.Add(new CustomAttributeArgument(systemTypeRef, module.Import(anothermodule.GetType("SampleDll.Annotation"))));
                methodDef.CustomAttributes.Add(custatt);

Comment: @MuruganAlagesan man you are making it hard to help you. What about pasting the full error messages to give a meaningful stacktrace?